# Android PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS and TelephonyManager#requestCellInfoUpdate return different signal strength

Tags: android, kotlin, telephonymanager, cellular-network

I want to monitor the cellular signal strength. My testing device use WCDMA.

```
telephonyManager.requestCellInfoUpdate(mainExecutor,object : TelephonyManager.CellInfoCallback() {
    override fun onCellInfo(allCellInfo: MutableList<CellInfo>) {
        allCellInfo.forEach {
            val s = (it as CellInfoWcdma).cellSignalStrength
            Log.d("requestCellInfoUpdate","ASU=${s.asuLevel}, dBm=${s.dbm}, level=${s.level}")
        }
    }
})
```

Gives `requestCellInfoUpdate: ASU=96, dBm=-24, level=4`

Looks fine, but I want to monitor the change. So I set up a `PhoneStateListener` (My device is Android 11, so no `registerTelephonyCallback` yet)

```
private val phoneStateListener : PhoneStateListener? = object: PhoneStateListener(){
    override fun onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength: SignalStrength?) {
        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            signalStrength?.cellSignalStrengths?.forEach {
                val s = it as CellSignalStrengthWcdma
                Log.d("onSignalStrengthsChanged","ASU=${s.asuLevel}, dBm=${s.dbm}, level=${s.level}")
            }
        }        
    }
}

telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS)
```

which gives me `onSignalStrengthsChanged: ASU=55, dBm=-65, level=4` instead

It seems that the value obtained by `PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS` is wrong, is it? Do I have to call `requestCellInfoUpdate` within `onSignalStrengthsChanged` to get the true signal strength?

It also seems that the ASU level get by `requestCellInfoUpdate` never update. If I put the phone in a microwave,

`requestCellInfoUpdate` gives `ASU=96, dBm=-24, level=1` while

`onSignalStrengthsChanged` gives `ASU=23, dBm=-97, level=2`.

I have no idea which value is right.